# Expressions in conjunction with “herunterladen”

Tags: verb, preposition, verb-usage

*Herunterladen* is the translation of *to download.* I would like to know which preposition(s) *herunterladen* takes, and how one refers to the source of downloading. Are the following expressions correct?

> Ich habe aus Youtube heruntergeladen
>
> Ich habe aus dem Internet heruntergeladen

And the location to be downloaded to:

> Ich habe es auf meinen Desktop/mein Handy heruntergeladen

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Richtig, "herunterladen" ist die deutsche Übersetzung von "to download".

Man lädt **aus** dem Internet **von** einem Server **auf** den Desktop. Deine Beispiele sind also fast richtig.

> Ich habe es **von** Youtube heruntergeladen.
>
> Ich habe es **aus** dem Internet heruntergeladen.
>
> Ich habe es **auf** meinen Desktop heruntergeladen.

Wie @Jan angemerkt hat, sagen Leute auch

> Ich habe es **im** Internet heruntergeladen.

Ich finde das aber unglücklich, weil *herunter*laden für mich eine Richtung bezeichnet (aus dem Internet auf meinen Rechner), und *im* Internet keine Richtung ausdrückt.

Comment: Youtube, etc. kann man auch als Netzwerk auffassen, daher würde ich "aus Youtube herunterladen" als weitere Möglichkeit durchaus gelten lassen.

Comment: I just want to add that *download* (or *herunterladen*) does not imply the Internet as source, it just implies any network. You cannot download from USB drive. The term *to download* means *to retrieve data from a network* (cf. Wikipedia, both English and German).

Comment: Im Zusammenspiel mit _von, aus_ und _auf_ kann _herunter_ weggelassen werden – das Verb ist dann also _laden_ –, vor allem wenn noch ein _mir_ dazu käme. Das funktioniert mit _im_ definitiv nicht. Während ggf. der substantivierte Infinitiv _das Herunterladen_ für den Prozess verwendet wird, gibt es kein deutsches Wort für das Resultat und entsprechend wird ein Anglizismus verwendet:  _der Download_.

Answer (score 1):

And actually, if you think about it, *herunterladen* is almost an implied verb nowadays, just like *gehen*.

> Wo kommt das her? Das habe ich von YouTube. Das habe ich aus dem Internet.

*Heruntergeladen* is implied (because how else would you get it? It wouldn’t come by mail on a USB drive, right?)

Of course, if you’re referring to saving something to the desktop, then you have to use the verb — heruntergeladen, gespeichert, kopiert, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your contribution. It would be great if you could elaborate your answer a bit with a word on prepositions. This was asked in the question and should be included in an answer. Thank you.

Comment: I must disagree, *heruntergeladen* is not specifically implied here.